# Stripe Connect Android

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am building an android app which pays someone. I explored Stripe Connect and it has an API and flow for website which requires displaying a stripe connect button and also needs a re-direct uri.

However, I can not find anything on for Android which allows to show a connect button and prompt user to create or connect a stripe account natively on Android device. Should I use a webview to do this or is there some more elegant way to do this?

Comment: see if this helps https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-stripe-connect

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, there're no native SDK for mobile stripe connect. I did the webview route for android. Was trivial, but I agree that I wished there're a more elegant solution to this.

For those who are wondering on how to do this (since I can't find any doc out there), here you go:

1. Create a button that will open a new intent with a web view.
2. The webview should load the oauth/authorize endpoint ("https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=[YOUR_API_KEY]&scope=read_write"). Do not forget to enable javascript on your webview.
3. Once the form in webview is filled, Stripe will redirect to the redirect_url you provided with the authorization code if the authorization is successful. Have your web service parse that authorization code.
4. Have your service make a post to stripe oauth/token with providing grant_type, client_id, code, and client_secret.
5. Stripe will then respond back with the token (auth credentials) that you needed. Store that for later use & you're pretty much done.

Comment: hi HungryMondkey, can you please tell me about redirect_url? what should be there in that url? i mean in html body etc?

Comment: Please can you give some information on how the web service works in this context? How do I receive the token from the web service back to the android app? If the web service needs to save the auth credentials, how do I send the user information so I can map the user on a particular app to the stripe auth credentials to be saved

Comment: Account form is not loading on step#2. how was this resolved?

Comment: Please provide more code

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old one but, After investing my 2 days and trying, searching a lot of techniques to create stripe account in android platform I found Stripe API which solves my problem...

Firstly, here is the [***jar***](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/releases/) file you have to include in your project.
Then you have to initialize key provided you at the dashboard

```
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.builder()
                                 .setApiKey("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").build();
Map<String, Object> accountParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   accountParams.put("managed", false);
   accountParams.put("country", "US");
   accountParams.put("email", "some@email.com");
```

1. To create an account use `create()` method for `Account` class with there parameter [***create link***](https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#create_account)

   ```
   try {
      Account create = Account.create(accountParams, null);
   } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
2. Then to retrieve account detail pass account id to `retrieve()` method

   ```
   try {
      Account detail = Account.retrieve("acct_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", null);
   } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

You can find more at [***Stripe Android API***](https://stripe.com/docs/api/java), and yes please do correct me if I am wrong..

> Exception you need to catch `AuthenticationException`, `InvalidRequestException`, `APIConnectionException`, `CardException`, `APIException`