# Android Stripe Connect WebView - Create Account Form NOT loading

Tags: android, firebase, webview, android-webview, stripe-payments

As is known, there is no Stripe Connect feature for Android unfortunately so I'm following [a somewhat known workaround using a webview like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52493606/stripe-connect-firebase-functions) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904041/stripe-connect-android). I'm trying to get my Webview for Stripe [Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts#integrating-oauth) to work however the form to fill out for creating a Stripe Connect Account doesn't load, only the top portion does. See **snippet#1**. However, if I open up my chrome browser on my android emulator, the entire form loads(form inside red box). See **snippet#2**

I have javascript enabled but it still doesn't load. See the code above snippets.

When I go to the URL on my computer and inspect, it loads normally, however, **the account form loads after the URL** it seems? I am not so familiar with React but I think it has something to do with that.

**URL**
https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ca_7O1mjnCTpkFRmHoS3B1awsXMEAdSrB6U&scope=read_write&stripe_user[business_type]=individual#

What I'm using:
Android
Firebase-Firestore
Firebase Cloud Functions
Stripe

Any and all help is appreciated.

**Code In Webview Activity**

```
val addPaymentSourceWebView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.add_payment_source_Webview);
val paymentWebViewSettings = addPaymentSourceWebView.settings
addPaymentSourceWebView.webViewClient
addPaymentSourceWebView.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled
addPaymentSourceWebView.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled
addPaymentSourceWebView.webChromeClient
addPaymentSourceWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled
addPaymentSourceWebView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically

addPaymentSourceWebView.settings.domStorageEnabled
addPaymentSourceWebView.settings.allowFileAccess
addPaymentSourceWebView.settings.allowContentAccess
addPaymentSourceWebView.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
addPaymentSourceWebView.settings.databaseEnabled
addPaymentSourceWebView.settings.mixedContentMode
addPaymentSourceWebView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode
addPaymentSourceWebView.settings.useWideViewPort
addPaymentSourceWebView.settings.allowFileAccessFromFileURLs
addPaymentSourceWebView.settings.allowFileAccessFromFileURLs


addPaymentSourceWebView.loadUrl("https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ca_7O1mjnCTpkFRmHoS3B1awsXMEAdSrB6U&scope=read_write&stripe_user[business_type]=individual#")
```

**Snippet#1**
[image]

**Snippet#2**
[image]

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6255353/379538

Comment: @floatingLomas, I wish it was. it still doesnt work. I think it has something to do with the form loading after the url has loaded. When I go to the URL on my laptop and inspect or in the chrome browser in the android, I can see its a react page and the account forms loads after the url. It might have something to do with an IFRAME in the HTML code?

Comment: Not sure what to suggest; maybe write into Support? https://support.stripe.com/contact/email